# Android Game Programming For Dummies High Score Storing

Tags: java, android, eclipse, storage

I'm currently making an app following the instructions for the Whack A Mole Game in the Android Game Programming For Dummies book, but I was wondering how to store highscores in xml or shared preferences or anything else so the data isn't lost when the app is closed. I already made sure there is a high score value that is being updated when there is a new high score, I only need it to be stored!

Comment: see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: Android Breakout uses the SharedPreferences approach; code here: https://code.google.com/p/android-breakout/source/browse/src/com/faddensoft/breakout/BreakoutActivity.java#267

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should just use shared preferences for now. I'd suggest you do it behind an `interface`. That way you can provide a simple `SharedPreferences` implementation for now. Then later replace if and when it's necessary.

Something like this (assuming you want names, even simpler if you don't):

```
public class Score {
   private String name;
   private int score;
   //getters/setters omitted
}

public interface ScoreBoard {
   void placeScore(Score score);
   List<Score> readTopScores(int count);
}
```

You can then provide implementations that talk to an sql store or even an external score service later (for example heyzap). Or if the user opts out, and for now, store them locally:

```
ScoreBoard scoreBoard = userWantsToUseHeyzap
                          ? new HeyZapScoreBoard()
                          : new SharedPreferencesScoreBoard(prefs);
```